# Isomorphism of groups involving quotients

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. I want to show that there is an isomorphism of groups $R/I^2 \cong R/I \oplus I/I^2$. I think that this should follow from some isomorphism theorem or Chinese remainder theorem, but I haven't been able to get it.

Answer (score 1):

The truth is that this claim is not true.

Example: $R = \mathbb Z$, $I = 2\mathbb Z$.

On the left you have $\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$, which is a cyclic group.

On the right you have $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$, which is not cyclic.

Comment: Ah yes thanks! Do you know if there are conditions on I for which it would be true?

Comment: From what I know, this is hardly true. One example where it's true might be taking $R = k[x]$ the polynomial ring and $I = xR$, for example.